# Pyspark window function with condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a DataFrame of events with time difference between each row, the main rule is that one visit is counted if only the event has been within 5 minutes of the previous or next event:

```python
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|userid  |eventtime          |timeDiff|
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:00:00|60      |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:01:00|60      |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:02:00|60      |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:03:00|180     |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:06:00|60      |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:07:00|420     |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:14:00|60      |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:15:00|1140    |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:34:00|540     |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:53:00|540     |
+--------+----------------- -+--------+
```

The challenge is to group by the start_time and end_time of the latest eventtime that has the condition of being within 5 minutes. The output should be like this table:

```python
+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|userid  |start_time         |end_time            |events     |
+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:00:00|2017-06-04 03:07:00 |6          |
|37397e29|2017-06-04 03:14:00|2017-06-04 03:15:00 |2          |
+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

So far I have used window lag functions and some conditions, however, I do not know where to go from here:

```python
%spark.pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

windowSpec = W.partitionBy(result_poi["userid"], result_poi["unique_reference_number"]).orderBy(result_poi["eventtime"])
windowSpecDesc = W.partitionBy(result_poi["userid"], result_poi["unique_reference_number"]).orderBy(result_poi["eventtime"].desc())

# The windows are between the current row and following row. e.g: 3:00pm and 3:03pm 
nextEventTime = F.lag(col("eventtime"), -1).over(windowSpec)

# The windows are between the current row and following row. e.g: 3:00pm and 3:03pm 
previousEventTime = F.lag(col("eventtime"), 1).over(windowSpec)
diffEventTime = nextEventTime - col("eventtime")

nextTimeDiff = F.coalesce((F.unix_timestamp(nextEventTime)
            - F.unix_timestamp('eventtime')), F.lit(0))
previousTimeDiff = F.coalesce((F.unix_timestamp('eventtime') -F.unix_timestamp(previousEventTime)), F.lit(0))


# Check if the next POI is the equal to the current POI and has a time differnce less than 5 minutes.
validation = F.coalesce(( (nextTimeDiff < 300) | (previousTimeDiff < 300) ), F.lit(False))

# Change True to 1
visitCheck = F.coalesce((validation == True).cast("int"), F.lit(1))


result_poi.withColumn("visit_check", visitCheck).withColumn("nextTimeDiff", nextTimeDiff).select("userid", "eventtime", "nextTimeDiff", "visit_check").orderBy("eventtime")
```

My questions: Is this a viable approach, and if so, how can I "go forward" and look at the maximum eventtime that fulfill the 5 minutes condition. To my knowledge, iterate through values of a Spark SQL Column, is it possible? wouldn't it be too expensive?. Is there another way to achieve this result?

**Result of Solution suggested by @Aku**:

```python
+--------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|userid  |subgroup|start_time           |end_time             |events|
+--------+--------+--------+------------+---------------------+------+
|37397e29|0       |2017-06-04 03:00:00.0|2017-06-04 03:06:00.0|5     |
|37397e29|1       |2017-06-04 03:07:00.0|2017-06-04 03:14:00.0|2     |
|37397e29|2       |2017-06-04 03:15:00.0|2017-06-04 03:15:00.0|1     |
|37397e29|3       |2017-06-04 03:34:00.0|2017-06-04 03:43:00.0|2     |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------+
```

It doesn't give the result expected. 3:07 - 3:14 and  03:34-03:43 are being counted as ranges within 5 minutes, it shouldn't be like that. Also, 3:07 should be the end_time in the first row as it is within 5 minutes of the previous row 3:06.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need one extra window function and a `groupby` to achieve this. 
What we want is for every line with timeDiff greater than 300 to be the end of a group and the start of a new one. Aku's solution should work, only the indicators mark the start of a group instead of the end. To change this you'll have to do a cumulative sum up to n-1 instead of n (n being your current line):

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("eventtime")
DF = DF.withColumn("indicator", (DF.timeDiff > 300).cast("int"))
DF = DF.withColumn("subgroup", func.sum("indicator").over(w) - func.col("indicator"))
DF = DF.groupBy("subgroup").agg(
    func.min("eventtime").alias("start_time"), 
    func.max("eventtime").alias("end_time"),
    func.count("*").alias("events")
 )

+--------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|subgroup|         start_time|           end_time|events|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|       0|2017-06-04 03:00:00|2017-06-04 03:07:00|     6|
|       1|2017-06-04 03:14:00|2017-06-04 03:15:00|     2|
|       2|2017-06-04 03:34:00|2017-06-04 03:34:00|     1|
|       3|2017-06-04 03:53:00|2017-06-04 03:53:00|     1|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

It seems that you also filter out lines with only one event, hence:

```py
DF = DF.filter("events != 1")

+--------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|subgroup|         start_time|           end_time|events|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|       0|2017-06-04 03:00:00|2017-06-04 03:07:00|     6|
|       1|2017-06-04 03:14:00|2017-06-04 03:15:00|     2|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 7):

So if I understand this correctly you essentially want to end each group when TimeDiff > 300? This seems relatively straightforward with rolling window functions:

First some imports

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
```

Then setting windows, I assumed you would partition by userid

```
w = Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("eventtime")
```

Then figuring out what subgroup each observation falls into, by first marking the first member of each group, then summing the column.

```
indicator = (TimeDiff > 300).cast("integer")
subgroup = func.sum(indicator).over(w).alias("subgroup")
```

Then some aggregation functions and you should be done

```
DF = DF.select("*", subgroup)\
.groupBy("subgroup")\
.agg(
    func.min("eventtime").alias("start_time"),
    func.max("eventtime").alias("end_time"),
    func.count(func.lit(1)).alias("events")
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Aku. It doesn't give the result expected. 3:07 - 3:14 and 03:34-03:43 are being counted as ranges within 5 minutes, it shouldn't be like that. I edited the question with the result of your suggested solution so you can verify.

Comment: So you want the start_time and end_time to be within 5 min of each other? That is not true for the example "desired output" (has a range of 3:00 - 3:07), so I'm rather confused.

Comment: Yes, exactly start_time and end_time to be within 5 min of each other. The end_time is 3:07 because 3:07 is within 5 min of the previous one: 3:06.

Answer (score 0):

Approach can be grouping the dataframe based on your timeline criteria.

You can create a dataframe with the rows breaking the 5 minutes timeline.
Those rows are criteria for grouping the records and
that rows will set the startime and endtime for each group.

Then find the count and max timestamp(endtime) for each group.

Comment: Thanks @Magic. I edited my question with the result of your solution which is similar to the one of Aku