# PySpark, kind of groupby, considering sequence

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this kind of dataset:

```
+------+------+------+
| Time | Tool | Hole |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | A    | H1   |
|    2 | A    | H2   |
|    3 | B    | H3   |
|    4 | A    | H4   |
|    5 | A    | H5   |
|    6 | B    | H6   |
+------+------+------+
```

The expected result is the following: It's a kind of temporal aggregation of my data, where the sequence is important.

```
+------+-----------+---------+
| Tool | Time_From | Time_To |
+------+-----------+---------+
| A    |         1 |       2 |
| B    |         3 |       3 |
| A    |         4 |       5 |
| B    |         6 |       6 |
+------+-----------+---------+
```

Current result,  with groupby statement doesn't match my expectation, as the sequence is not considered.

```
+------+-----------+---------+
| Tool | Time_From | Time_To |
+------+-----------+---------+
| A    |         1 |       5 |
| B    |         3 |       5 |
+------+-----------+---------+

rdd = rdd.groupby(['tool']).agg(min(rdd.time).alias('minTMSP'),
                                    max(rdd.time).alias('maxTMSP'))
```

I tried to pass through a window function, but without any result so far... Any idea how I could handle this use case in pyspark?

Comment: Take a look into this answer with window function - it should help, if not I'll post solution for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737199/pyspark-window-function-with-condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `lag` function and `Window` class to check if the entry in each row has changed with regard to its previous row. We can then calculate the cumulative sum using this same `Window` to find our column to group by. From that point on it is straightforward to find the minimum and maximum times per group.

Hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'A'), (2,'A'), (3,'B'),(4,'A'),(5,'A'),(6,'B')], 
                           schema=['Time','Tool'])

w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('Time')

df2 = (df.withColumn('Tool_lag',F.lag(df['Tool']).over(w))
.withColumn('equal',F.when(F.col('Tool')==F.col('Tool_lag'), F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.lit(1)))
.withColumn('group', F.sum(F.col('equal')).over(w))
.groupBy('Tool','group').agg(
    F.min(F.col('Time')).alias('start'),
    F.max(F.col('Time')).alias('end'))
.drop('group'))
df2.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+---+
|Tool|start|end|
+----+-----+---+
|   A|    1|  2|
|   B|    3|  3|
|   A|    4|  5|
|   B|    6|  6|
+----+-----+---+
```